# What do you call these in English?

Tags: vocabulary

I think the title says it all. 
Are they called boxes? Columns? I really don't know. It you could help me, that would be very useful :)[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm afraid the title does not say it all.  What specifically are you asking about? I see some boxes in that image. There's also some text, some triangles, some lines and some squiggles.

Comment: I usually call things like this ***picklists***, but really this looks like a matter of "domain-specific terminology" that might be more properly addressed on [SE User Experience.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about domain-specific terminology

Comment: The “dropdown lists?” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-down_list

Comment: English is not my native language and couldn't find any suitable words for the 'boxes' in the picture in any dictionary, that's why I'm asking on the forum.

Comment: I just wondered how would you refer to them?

Comment: If I want to unambiguously direct someone's attention to those things, I call them 'dropdowns'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic term for small clickable things on screens is **widgets**.

Try [JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com), which has a list of common widgets and some visual examples.